# Creating Multiple Debian Packages with cmake

Tags: cmake, deb, cpack

I have a cmake project consisting of a set of executable files, independent of each other with two shared libraries. I want to pack each executable file into a deb package.
As a result, I get one deb package with all programs and libs.

part of the source code:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)

set (CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
set (CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "i am")
set (CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL 1)
include (CPack)

add_executable (module1 main.cpp)
install (TARGETS module1 
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin 
        COMPONENT component1)

add_library (my_lib SHARED map.cpp templates.cpp)
add_executable (my_lib main.cpp utils.cpp)
target_link_libraries (module2 PUBLIC my_lib)

install(TARGETS module2 my_lib
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        COMPONENT component2)
```

How to divide programs into different deb packages?

Answer (score 5):

Well that's the answer

```
set (CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
set (CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "Your name")
set (CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)
include (CPack)

function (add_package TARGET_NAME TARGET_PATH DESCR)
    install(TARGETS "${TARGET_NAME}"
            DESTINATION "${TARGET_PATH}"
            COMPONENT "${TARGET_NAME}")

    cpack_add_component_group("${TARGET_NAME}")

    cpack_add_component("${TARGET_NAME}"
                        DISPLAY_NAME "${TARGET_NAME}"
                        DESCRIPTION "${DESCR}"
                        GROUP "${TARGET_NAME}"
                        INSTALL_TYPES Full)
endfunction ()

add_executable (my_program1 main.cpp)
add_package(my_program1 "bin" "Description")

add_executable (my_program2 main.cpp)
add_package(my_program2 "bin" "Description")
```

and run in terminal

```
make package
```